# Find multiple nearby points in a DataFrame Python

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoDataFrame containing lat/lon coordinates, and points (with the corresponding coordinates), extracted from a raster. I would like to classify the points by their proximity (fixed distance for example), into different groups (in order to create polygons lately).

I've searched for hours trying different solutions, and tried to implement different algorithms, nevertheless nothing is working for me.

Comment: Instead of stating you've tried a bunch of things, in order for your Question to be answerable, you should include the trial that came closest to working.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the points? And the point coordinates as text to be able to reproduce you dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work but it depends on the spatial distribution of your points. I use the [DBSCAN algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

#Create a geodataframe
df = pd.read_csv(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/4000_latlongs.csv')
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda x: Point(x['xcoord'], x['ycoord']), axis=1) #My lat/long columns are called ycoord/xcoord
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=df['geometry'], crs="EPSG:4326")

#Calculate x and y columns
df = df.to_crs(epsg='32633') #Reproject to a crs with units in meters instead of degrees. Change 32633 to a local crs where you are located
df['x'] = df.geometry.x #Create a x coordinate column (with units in meters)
df['y'] = df.geometry.y

#Cluster
coords = df[['x','y']].values #Create a numpy array where each row is a coordinate pair

#array([[ 694455.37762641, 7455507.93923842],
#       [ 659868.57157602, 7504387.51909201], ...])

db = DBSCAN(eps=4000, min_samples=2).fit(coords) #4000 is max distance between points, min cluster size are 2 points. You'll have to tweak the distance
cluster_labels = pd.Series(db.labels_).rename('cluster') #A series with all points cluster ids

df = pd.concat([df, cluster_labels], axis=1) #concat it to the dataframe
df.to_file(filename=r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/4000_latlongs_clustered.shp')
```

[image]

Comment: It worked fine for me! Nevertheless, when using larger datasets I employed the OPTICS function (very simmilar to DBSCAN), in order to avoid memory errors. Thanks!!